# Colorful text on custom text editor

Tags: c#, colors, editor

I've created a custom text editor with C# . Now, i would like to add the syntax highlighting feature by coloring the last letter/number that was inputted, in a way that the color that will be used is to be drawn on a random basis . How can i do so, though? I tried a bunch of alternative ways but none worked . Thanks for your recommendations! (Note: I've been coding for 2 months. Sorry for any mistakes ! )

Latest example :

```
    private void userTB_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        Random rnd = new Random();

        Color randomColor = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(255), rnd.Next(255), rnd.Next(255));

        userTB.SelectionColor = randomColor;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting "static" in front of your variable declaration.

```
       static Random rnd = new Random();
```

Your code is getting fired off by a button event, and so the Random variable is getting created anew each time the button is clicked, and so it begins its random sequence at the same starting point each time.

=====
Grayish?  Hmm.  Try this perhaps...

```
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    static int r1;
    static int r2;
    static int r3;

    r1 = rnd.Next(255);
    r2 = rnd.Next(255);
    r3 = rnd.Next(255);
    Color randomColor = Color.FromArgb(r1, r2, r3);
```

and take a look at the r1, r2, and r3 values in the debugger.

Comment: Trying moving rnd out of userTB_KeyPress into the surrounding class.

Comment: Also, is this color change simply happening *after* the character has been displayed?  when it would not have any effect?

Comment: I did move it out of the method for key press. This is happening simultaneously, meaning that after the key has been pressed and before it gets printed, its color changes to a random color.

Comment: If it isn't working, try putting a breakpoint in userTB_KeyPress and look at the value of rnd while the program is running.

Comment: For some reason its only printing either red or gray/whiteish  :/ .

Comment: Good!  I think that the code optimizer was treating the 3 uses of rnd.Next(255) as 1 value repeated -- which produces grey/white tones.  My final suggestion _forced_ the code optimizer to make 3 separate calls to rnd.Next(255), and produce 3 distinct result values.

Answer (score 0):

. On My Point View, The Colorization Will Happen Via Code Behind As In Background Too... You Will Need a Classe Specialized On Read Each Word And Recognise What Each Word Do...

. Your Text Editor Is About What?

Comment: My text editor is pretty much for any use as the regular Windows text editor. Not to be used as a IDE but as a regular .txt

Comment: Start Learning About FlowDocuments